# How to handle bidirectional relationship in DBUnit?

Tags: java, foreign-keys, constraints, dbunit

I have two entities that have foreign keys to each other. Of course they must be put in the xml dataset in particular order so that one of them do not know about the other. DBunit throws exception about constraint violation parsing the first one. How to handle this? It's so obvious case but I cannot find any solutions! How to do such a trivial thing? Is this  possible after all?

I'm trying to do that using deferStatement but it doesn't help even if the database implementation that I use do support it [like stated here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sessions-chapt.html)...

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void setupDB() throws DataSetException, DatabaseUnitException, SQLException, IOException {
        FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();

        builder.setColumnSensing(true);
        builder.setCaseSensitiveTableNames(true);

        final ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PropertiesConfiguration.class,
                PersistenceConfiguration.class);
        DataSource dataSource = appContext.getBean(DataSource.class);

        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement deferStatement = connection.createStatement();
        deferStatement.execute("SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED");
        DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection(connection);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        DatabaseOperation.TRANSACTION(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT).execute(databaseConnection,
                builder.build(inputStream));

        log.debug("Database initialized with data from dataset.");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: DBUnit uses one transaction per inserted row, which sucks. It's possible to hack the code to avoid that, but you'll still have a chicken and egg problem if one of the constraints is not deferred, or if you don't use updates rather than inserts. Shameless plug: use DbSetup instead: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: How to get those constraints deferred? Thanks for the library - I'll try it out in the next project - I must stick to DBUnit in this one.

Comment: It depends on your database, and if it supports them. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm for Oracle.

Comment: I'm using H2-inmemory database. What a shame, how could they forget about so obvious case...?